# How to run vba macro after an access form has loaded?

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I call a sub in Form_Load, it gives me an error cause by Screen.ActiveForm. This is due to the form not being loaded yet.

What sub/function can I use to run a macro once the form has loaded.

- I tried Form_Timer, it didn't do anything
- Form_Activate produces same error
- Form_after… they do not really seem to indicating anything after form load.

Here is my code for Form_Timer:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    call Module6.loadRecords
    Me.TimerInterval = 500
End Sub
```

I was hoping that after 0.5 seconds that my form will be loaded and records will be display in the form controls.

Comment: Are you trying to run this before or after? You say after, but in your last sentence you say "after 0.5 seconds that my form will be loaded and records will be displayed in the form controls." So are you trying to run something before, or after? Is this the initial Form?

Comment: @Pants I want call Module6.loadRecords when the form loads. The issue with that is that in my loadRecords sub I'm looking for "activeForm" but there is no active form while the form loads... which is why I want to put the call to loadrecords to after the form loads... unless you know of a different way of calling activeForm ( I use this because in modules you need to specify which form you want to load records in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of depending on `Screen.ActiveForm`, you should simply pass the form reference to the function.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call Module6.loadRecords(Me)
End Sub
```

and

```
Public Sub loadRecords(F As Access.Form)
```

---

If you really want to use `Screen.ActiveForm`, it works like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' 1 ms is enough to de-couple the events
    Me.TimerInterval = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    ' Reset timer, always the first thing to do for single Timer events
    Me.TimerInterval = 0

    Call Module6.loadRecords
End Sub
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I decided to go with your first suggestion. Thank you!